# Terraform forcing new resources on every apply

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm making a small VM in [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/), with one disk base image, and wish to manage my GCP infra with HashiCorp's [Terraform](http://terraform.io/) Here's the basic TF code I'm running:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "blog" {
    image = "ubuntu-1604-lts"
}
resource "google_compute_instance" "blog-vm" {
    disk {
        disk = "${google_compute_disk.blog.id}"
        auto_delete = false
    }
}
```

When I `tf apply`, it works fine the first time. But subsequent plans want to rebuild the disk, and thus the VM itself.

```
-/+ google_compute_disk.blog
    image:                      "ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20170619a" =>
                                "ubuntu-1604-lts" (forces new resource)
```

My goal here is to pick the latest ubuntu-lts template on image creation, but to leave the disk alone if created. Is this possible in Terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution to this class of problem is the `ignore_changes` lifecycle setting, which causes Terraform to ignore changes to specific attributes when creating a plan.

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "blog" {
  image = "ubuntu-1604-lts"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["image"]
  }
}
```

With this in place, Terraform will not automatically plan to replace the disk when `image` changes. If you *do* want to replace the disk for a new image, it'd be necessary to manually taint it:

```
$ terraform taint google_compute_disk.blog
```

This marks the instance as "tainted" in the state, which means the next plan will include a step to destroy the disk and create a new one in its place. Since the instance then uses that disk, the plan will also update or replace that as necessary.